# 2 cards in a row with the same height in Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

[image]I can't solve the issue of 2 card having different height.
Ideally, I want the buttons to be on the same position no matter how much content I include in either of cards.
I found some solutions, but they are not allowing cards go full width when on mobile version (for responsiveness). Is there anything I'm missing here?

(Parent container on the pic is gray for visibility)

```
  <div className="bg-gray-300 flex  flex-row flex-wrap  content-center justify-center ">
      <div className="h-full bg-white lg:w-1/2 md:w-full py-4 px-4 sm:px-8 lg:py-20 lg:px-40 z-20 ">
        <h2 className="text-3x1 font-extrabold text-black sm:text-4xl text-center">
          <span className="block">Title 1</span>
        </h2>
        <p className="text-black text-lg mt-6">
          <img
            className="object-contain h-48 w-96"
            src="/images/logo.png"
          ></img>
        Content 1
        </p>
        <div className="lg:mt-0 lg:flex-shrink-0">
          <div className=" mt-12 inline-flex rounded-md shadow">
            <button
              type="button"
              className="py-2 px-4  bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-700 focus:ring-gray-100 focus:ring-offset-blue-200 text-white w-full transition ease-in duration-200 text-center text-base font-semibold shadow-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2  rounded-lg "
            >
             Button 1
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className=" h-full bg-white lg:w-1/2 md:w-full bg-gray py-4 px-4 sm:px-8 lg:py-20 lg:px-40 z-20">
        <h2 className="text-3x1 font-extrabold text-black sm:text-4xl text-center">
          <span className="block ">Title 2</span>
        </h2>
        <p className="text-black text-lg mt-6">
          <img
            className="object-contain h-48 w-96"
            src="/images/package.png"
          ></img>
         Content 2
        </p>
        <div className="h-full lg:mt-0 lg:flex-shrink-0">
          <div className="px-4 mt-12 inline-flex rounded-md shadow">
            <button
              type="button"
              className="py-2 px-4  bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-700 focus:ring-gray-100 focus:ring-offset-blue-200 text-white w-full transition ease-in duration-200 text-center text-base font-semibold shadow-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2  rounded-lg "
            >
            Button 2
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`flex-grow` should do the trick. You need to remove `h-full` in order for this to work. Also, you can get the buttons to the bottom of the card by using `mt-auto`. I made a Tailwind Play as an example (I cleaned up the code a little bit just to make it easier to demo).

https://play.tailwindcss.com/kJRINyolVE

[More on the `flex-grow` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)